# Is an Italian Greagle a quiet enough dog to have in an apartment?

Tags: dogs, crossbreed

I recently heard about the mix/designer breed known as the Italian Greagle, an Italian Greyhound and Beagle mix.  They are very beautiful dogs, with the elegance of the Italian greyhound but with a slightly more filled out build.  My question is how much the Italian greyhound genes minimize the beagle's persistent vocalization?  In other words, are they quiet enough for apartment living or do they retain too much of the beagle genes?

Comment: I don't know about noisiness, but I imagine that dog would be rather high energy to be keeping it in an apartment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is - it's next to impossible to say for sure. Breed characteristics are ... to paraphrase a wise man 'more like guidelines'. There is absolutely no guarantee that any dog you get will be barky - or not.

You can improve the odds a little by going for a known quantity - adopting a dog with a history. There are no shortage of dogs in need of re-homing, either via rescues or privately. Although you should be wary of the ones that are looking to turn a profit on the transaction - they're less likely to have the best interest of you and the dog in mind.

However you need to be prepared to work with your dog and an ongoing commitment to optimising behaviour. That's not a small thing, but it's true of *any* dog. Some dogs are more laid back than others, but they *all* benefit from plenty of attention, training and exercise.

So I would suggest strongly that you don't think in terms of "Is this (breed of) dog quiet enough to have in an apartment" - because *all* of them can be. But none of them will be, unless you're prepared to take the time and commitment necessary.

Which means:

- proactively attend training for both your benefit - your dog has to learn how to speak your variety of 'human' and you have to understand their variety of 'dog'.
- Take time to train and reinforce positive behaviours, and avoid negative. (Training 'don't bark' is difficult).
- Look up separation anxiety, and consider it - it's often a factor in dogs annoying neighbours, because they do miss 'their' human. This can lead to whining and barking.
- Commit to regular exercise regime for your dog. There is an adage - a tired dog is a happy dog. So be prepared for an hour of walkies morning and evening. (Chances are, you won't need so much, but you need to be prepared for the possiblity - or even more)

I am personally of the opinion that negative reinforcement - such as bark collars - aren't a good thing to go for, as they can have some potentially unpredictable consequences. Consider for example - your dog sees a (potential) threat and barks to warn it off. And the collar "punishes" them for doing that. Have you just taught it not to bark, or have you just taught it that that thing definitely is a threat, and so they need to be more aggressive next time? Dogs don't stop pulling on a lead that is choking them, because the stress reinforces their need to 'fight back'. You can quite easily create the same situation accidentally with a 'bark collar'.

Comment: your last item: "or be prepared for even more"

Comment: True. Amended. My lil' husky cross will take 4 hours a day, and still be asking for more. (But it wasn't entirely unexpected, even if it would be nice to have a day off once in a while - she'll cope with a mere hour and a half a day though).

Comment: Yes, I know what it's like, I managed to find a very nice doggy day care and I'm taking 2 days off a week.

Comment: We use a doggy daycare. It's brilliant. I think that might be my new career plan too.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know anything about this breed, but being around many different breeds of dogs, it mostly depends on the dogs personality, your training activities (this includes socializing and exposing the dog to new things and environments), and how much exercise/play time the dog gets.

I've had a few Rottweilers and they were all different with their vocalization levels. My mom has had a few Mini Schnauzers; some barked excessively and others that did not make a peep. My dad has had a few Scottish terriers and a few Standard Schnauzers where some barked at every noise they could not see and some who cared less and never barked.

Bark collars do work in some cases. We have used them on all our dogs that barked excessively once we left the house. For example one dog had found a way around the bark collar activation by whining instead of barking which now the neighbors think the dog wants to play with their dog.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Italian Greagles being quiet, it really depends on training. Mine was trained to bark to let me know someone is around, she was also trained to actually put herself between me and someone if they are hitting me. I love her and worry about her anytime she gets sick or doesn't act her normal self.

Comment: Completely agree, have female rescue (literally almost got hit by car at approx 7-8 mths) only issue-separation anxiety now. She has picked up quickly what is ok and not in our house and has taken almost a year of the long lead to get her to point of not taking off after any noise in woods. She is extremely attentive and let's is know but not with barking just with running from window to door. Mostly quiet except when someone is in yard that doesn't belong or hears someone coming up gravel drive way. if gotten from pup lots of energy and I think highly trainable for apartment living.

Answer (score 0):

I have a beagle italian greyhound mix we adopted when she was 6 months old. 
She only barks when she hears an unfamiliar noise or when someone comes to the door.  But the first things we taught her was speak and shush so that may have helped.

The first time I heard her bay like a beagle she ended up scaring herself - it was also the first time she met a cow. Also sometimes when I have her out off-leash she will bay at new critters but when I say shush she stops.

I was also lucky and achieved full off leash control with her. I am very glad too, because she is fast enough to run down and grab a rabbit....

I took her on a hunting trip with my friend and his 3 beagles that he trained to run rabbits and we didn't even get a chance to shoot any that trip. She would take off and catch them and bring them to us!

We did eventually get her trained to not do that anymore for fear of her accidentally getting shot. She also likes to track and snatch flies out of the air.

Comment: This is an interesting anecdote, but it really doesn't add anything to the existing answers.